# ActionBarActivity changes default styling of EditText

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-theme, android-actionbaractivity

I am facing issue that my EditText showing loosing its default styling.
I have creating Custom Toolbar but I am not including it for debugging purpose.
If my activity extends normal Activity then I getting correct styling(**the line below EditText is of default styling i.e corners are facing upwards**) for EditText

```
class UploadActivity extends Activity{

}
```

[image]

**Issue:**
If my class extends ActionbarActivity then the styling changes i.e I am not getting the line below EditText having **corners facing upwards**. I am using UploadTheme for the Activity.

```
class UploadActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

}
```

style.xml

```
<style name="UploadTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/appBackground</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/appBackground</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
```

[image]

How I can achieve that using ActionBarActivity?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that when using `ActionBarActivity` (which should now be using `AppCompatActivity`) in combination with the AppCompat theme, it will style TextViews using the AppCompat style (which is the flat line/material styling). If you want the Holo style, you need to explicitly declare that for the EditTexts.

So in your Styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditTextStyle"  parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText">  
</style>
```

And then for the EditText's, add:

```
style="@android:style/AppTheme.EditTextStyle"
```